# What is the meaning of "Cold Cut King of Long Island"?

Tags: dialogue, american-hustle

In *American Hustle* Irving said his friend Ed Malone is Cold Cut King of Long Island. What does that mean?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure which part of the phrase is confusing, but I'll give it a shot.

A "cold cut" is another name for a thin slice of cold processed meats or other cooked meats. Examples include thin-cut ham or baloney.

If someone is the "cold cut king", then presumably that person either sells a lot of cold cuts (slices of cooked or processed meats), or eats a lot of cold cuts.

Naming a location implies that the person is known throughout that area for eating or selling a lot of cold cuts.

Comment: Unrelated but in one of my favorite movies, Ferris Bueller impersonates Abe Froman, Sausage King of Chicago at a very fancy French restaurant and upon successfully deceiving the Maitre D' receives excellent service, so I would presume from context that the first definition, a person who has made a lot of money from that industry is the correct one